# im getting an error on post and get method. im using django framework

Tags: django, django-forms

[26/Feb/2024 13:03:35] "GET /registration/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6389
Method Not Allowed (POST): /registration/
Method Not Allowed: /registration/
[26/Feb/2024 13:03:44] "POST /registration/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
try to get the user username and password on the database.but it showign error e.g method not allowed

Comment: Can you post the view you are using? It appears you are trying to use some GET request when a POST request is needed

Comment: Please share the view’s code? And also the http request code from the frontend.